# how to split a double and show it in 2 fields

Tags: spring, hibernate, jstl

In my JSP, I am using a list to iterate the values and show them in JSP. Some of my values are double like

```
<td>Length <form:input path="rr.length"/> </td>
```

which will show `123.45` in the filed.

But, in my jsp I want to show them as

integer part in one filed and decimal part in another field with a dot in between the fields.

`123` . `45`

when user edits the data, it should save as one field in DB. I am using spring form tags in my jsp. Using spring MVC, Hibernate, JSP and JSTL.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I hate to say it, but maybe you should just let it display as a number and move on to something that actually matters

Comment: it actually matters...displayed as number..unfortunately they want it this way.. :(

Comment: The easiest way for me seams to use some java script stuff for this task.

Comment: usually we see this kind in phone apps(bank apps)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this mask plugin?
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/